# Show that $\mathbb{F}_p^\times \simeq \text{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_p^+) $ holds

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I want to show, that  $\mathbb{F}_p^\times  \simeq \text{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_p^+)$ holds with $p$ prime.
($\mathbb{F}_p^+$ is the additive group, $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ multiplicative group)

As hint we got the following homomorphism
$$ \Phi :\mathbb{F}_p^+ \rightarrow \text{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_p^+), \ g \mapsto (x \mapsto g+x+(-g)) $$
$\text{kern}(\Phi)=\mathbb{F}_p^+$ because $\mathbb{F}_p^+$ is abelian and $\text{im}(\Phi)=\{\text{id}\}$.

I thought to create another homomorphism
$$ \Phi' : \mathbb{F}_p^\times \rightarrow \text{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_p^+), \ g \mapsto (x \mapsto g \cdot x) $$
It is clear that $\text{kern}(\Phi')=\{\overline{1}\}$ and it follows $\mathbb{F}_p^ \times \simeq \text{im}(\Phi') \subseteq \text{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_p^+)$.

How do I know, that there are not more automorphisms?

Comment: You ought to write something like ${\mathbb F}_p^+$ for the additive group. By default, ${\rm Aut}({\mathbb F}_p)$ denotes the automorphism group of the *field* of order $p$. If $p$ is prime, then this group is trivial.

Comment: @DerekHolt : thanks for your comment. I also forgot to mention, that $p$ have to be prime. I also fixed the notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: The additive group $\Bbb F_p$ is cyclic, generated by any non-zero class. Now, an automorphism of $\Bbb F_p$ is a homomorphism
$$
f:\Bbb F_p\longrightarrow\Bbb F_p
$$
and a homomorphism between cyclic groups is completely determined by the image of a single chosen generator.

This should convince you that the map $\Phi^\prime$ you defined is surjective.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbf{F}_p$ is a cyclic group. You know a lot about group homomorphisms whose domain is a cyclic group.